# Invalid input in the Browser of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm getting this error in Neo4j Browser after my query

```
CREATE(ARTMPA12:Articulo{ISBN:4,vol:'',num:'',edit:'',titulo:'',nameevento:'',alcance:'interNational'abstract:'',numpags:'',rutapdf:'',palabraClave1:'datamatching',palabraClave2:'deduplication',palabraClave3:'record linkage',anio:2015})
```

And the error is this

> Invalid input 'b': expected 'n/N' (line 1, column 103 (offset: 102))
> "CREATE(ARTMPA12:Articulo{ISBN:4,vol:'',num:'',edit:'',titulo:'',nameevento:'',alcance:'interNational'abstract:'',numpags:'',rutapdf:'',palabraClave1:'data matching',palabraClave2:'deduplication',palabraClave3:'record linkage',anio:2015})"

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have missed a semicolon in the cypher query:

CREATE(ARTMPA12:Articulo{ISBN:4,vol:'',num:'',edit:'',titulo:'',nameevento:'',**alcance:'interNational'abstract:''**,numpags:'',rutapdf:'',palabraClave1:'datamatching',palabraClave2:'deduplication',palabraClave3:'record linkage',anio:2015})

It should be like below:

```
CREATE(ARTMPA12:Articulo{ISBN:4,vol:'',num:'',edit:'',titulo:'',nameevento:'',alcance:'interNational',abstract:'',numpags:'',rutapdf:'',palabraClave1:'datamatching',palabraClave2:'deduplication',palabraClave3:'record linkage',anio:2015})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma before abstract.

```
 CREATE(ARTMPA12:Articulo{ISBN:4,vol:'',num:'', 
     edit:'',titulo:'',nameevento:'',alcance:'interNational',
     abstract:'',numpags:'',rutapdf:'',
      palabraClave1:'datamatching',
      palabraClave2:'deduplication',
      palabraClave3:'record linkage',anio:2015})
```